# NodeJS Express create Mongoose query from string

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I have this string:

```
var filter = '{stamps:{$gte: 2020-11-06 06:42:25.000+01:00, $lte: 2020-11-06 09:52:25.000+01:00}'
```

Somehow I have to query mongoDB collection with this string.

```
Message.find(filter, function(err, messages){
  if(err){
    console.log(err);
  }else{
    //do something here
  }
})
```

Of course I am getting this error:

```
ObjectParameterError: Parameter "filter" to find() must be an object, got {stamps:{$gte: 2020-11-06 06:42:25.000+01:00, $lte: 2020-11-06 09:52:25.000+01:00}
```

is there some way to cast this string to object that will be acceptable to mongoDB?

Comment: What about `JSON.parse(filter)`?

Comment: WHat is filter? Mongooose document?

Comment: after JSON.parse(filter) i am getting this error - SyntaxError: Unexpected token s in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Comment: @Richard Rublev filter is a string I am getting trough URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either change the way you construct your query, to pass it as JSON an then use `JSON.parse()` / `JSON.stringify()`

```
// Note the necessary double quotes around the keys
const jsonFilter = '{ "stamps": { "$gte": "2020-11-06 06:42:25.000+01:00", "$lte": "2020-11-06 09:52:25.000+01:00" } }'
const query = JSON.parse(jsonFilter)
Message.find(query, callback)
```

---

Or you could introduce another dependency like [mongodb-query-parser](https://github.com/mongodb-js/query-parser) that can parse the string for you.

```
const parser = require('mongodb-query-parser')
// Note it still needs double quotes around the dates to run properly
const filter = '{stamps:{$gte: "2020-11-06 06:42:25.000+01:00", $lte: "2020-11-06 09:52:25.000+01:00" } }'
const query = parser(filter)
Message.find(query, callback)
```

https://runkit.com/5fbd473b95d0a9001a2359b3/5fbd473b98492c001a8bba06

---

If you can't include the quotes around the values in the string, you can use a regular expression to add them. But keep in mind that this regex is tailored to match this exact date format. If the format can change or you want to also match other data types, you should try to include them in your filter string from the start.

```
const parser = require("mongodb-query-parser")
const filter = '{stamps:{$gte: 2020-11-06 06:42:25.000+01:00, $lte: 2020-11-06 09:52:25.000+01:00} }'
const filterWithQuotedDates = filter.replace(/(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3}(\+\d{2}:\d{2})?)/g, '"$1"')
parser(filterWithQuotedDates)
Message.find(query, callback)
```

https://runkit.com/5fbd494bcd812c0019b491fb/5fbd4951ebe43f001a5b590a

---

It should be noted that a common use-case is to pass a MongoDB query via URL params and that there are special packages for that:

- https://github.com/Turistforeningen/node-mongo-querystring
- https://github.com/fox1t/qs-to-mongo

Comment: i tried mongodb-query-parser but i am getting this error - SyntaxError: Unexpected token (1:27)

Comment: @Benno I am also getting the same error,can you reproduce the code?

Comment: @VladimirSarac the problem is the missing quotes around the dates. Do you have the possibility to include them? Otherwise they can be added e.g. via a Regex..

https://runkit.com/5fbd473b95d0a9001a2359b3/5fbd473b98492c001a8bba06

Comment: @RichardRublev here's a version that adds quotes around the dates with a simple regular expression https://runkit.com/5fbd494bcd812c0019b491fb/5fbd4951ebe43f001a5b590a

Comment: @VladimirSarac Glad I could help. Please consider marking my answer as accepted if it solved your problem